# Specifying recipient of SharePoint variations notifications

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm creating a new SharePoint 2010 (Enterprise) site, that will use variations, but have a couple of questions about notification emails:

1. when setting up variations in the site collection settings, there is an option for "Notification", which states "*Send e-mail notification to site and page contacts when a new site or page is created, or a page is updated by the variation system.*"
   We plan to have 6 variations: English US as the source, English UK, French, German, Dutch and Spanish as targets, with different content authors for each target variation.
   How can I set up the "site and page contacts" so that each author gets an email for the target variation they are responsible for? i.e. where are "site and page contacts" defined?
2. I'm currently thinking that I will be disabling "Variations Propagate Page Job Definition", so that updates to the English US source pages won't propagate the target variations of the page, undoing any manual translation or slight changes.
   Given that, will using the "Update" and "Create" buttons in the variations section of the Publishing ribbon still work, and if so will it still send the notifications (given that I do question 1 above)

Hopefully, these two questions make sense, but if I need to clarify anything, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

1) use a group, yes everyone gets notified, but that way you set the Contact to the group on the source variation and it just flows down from there. (I think this should work)

2) Leave it on. when you publish changes it creates a new draft version, which your author would have to edit and publish, take a look at this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2010/05/05/view-changes-makes-in-browser-content-localization-easier.aspx)